# Re-sloping given DEM to pre-determined slope in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, slope

I have a set of topographic contours of a mine and like to re-slope those areas alongside the river to a pre-determined slope, say 22˚; and 27˚ for water pond wall. The existing slopes along the river and the water pond vary from 5˚ to 32˚.

Does anyone know any tools in ArcGIS 10.1 can be used to perform this specific task?

Comment: Are you just trying to insert or mask values in a slope raster?

Comment: Indeed I need to re-contour the topography of the mine so that the new slopes can meet the pre-determined ones which are within the areas noted in my primary question.

Comment: If you have that as a raster then you can either Con with raster calculator or mosaic using *first* or *last* depending on the order of your images.